# Two TextViews on the same line

Tags: java, android, xml

Hoping this is a simple one

I want two textviews on the same line aligned to the left.

Currently my layout is as shown:

[image]

I want this layout(note i modified the diagram on paint):

[image]

here is the xml i currently have:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSetItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

    android:focusable="false" />
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSetAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSetPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm your layout shouldn't compile-- there is no attribute `android:layout_width` on the TextView objects.

To fix this, remove `layout_weight` and set `layout_width` to `wrap_content`

Anyways, here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="This"
/>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="this"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first TextView's weight to 0 (or to something smaller than 1). You're giving them equal weight and LinearLayout places them in a way that gives them equal width, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `weight`.
Use `wrap_content` on the `layout_width`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you are looking for:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to go about this would be to use relative layout .
You can change how "close" or "far" apart the two textviews will be using changing the         android:layout_marginLeft property on textView2.
The following property:
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
makes sure that tv2 is aligned with tv1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```